# How to install older Solidity versions on Ubuntu 18.04 using the Terminal

Tags: solidity

I'm attempting to install Solidity version 0.3.2 from GitHub via source code for compiling purposes.

I was initially running 0.5.0 and I managed to update Solidity but when I tried to install previous versions, version 0.5.1 still shows as my current version installed.

I ran `chmod +x solc-static-linux` for version 0.4.25 on Terminal as a test and that did not replace version 0.5.1 either.

What should I do? Thanks.